# Laravel error 'Integrity constraint violation' inserting into databse

Tags: php, laravel

I get the below error when trying to insert into my database table:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`test`.`deviceinfo`, CONSTRAINT `deviceinfo_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`sid`) REFERENCES `siteinfo` (`sid`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION) (SQL: insert into `deviceinfo` (`dinfo`, `sid`, `DeviceType`, `CreatePID`, `UpdatePID`, `CreateDTime`) values (abcd, [129:4002/1/3/JuronEast123], 12345, something, something, 2014-08-20 09:48:46))

How do I fix it?

Comment: Can you specify which version of Laravel this is in. It’s either 3 or 4, not both.

Answer (score 0):

it's just a key constraint violation. looks like your input for `sid` can't be referenced with `siteinfo.sid`.

with the infos you shared i assume `sid` is an integer.

therefore you'd need to fill the `[129:4002/1/3/JuronEast123]` value on the **siteinfo** relationship on the **deviceinfo** model. here again, i'm assuming you're using eloquent, since you tagged it as laravel.